# Tooltip remains sometimes on page on element inside sliding div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

We are using a bootstrap for one of the project and facing an issue with tooltip plugin provided. Its actually not a bug in bootstrap but an issue is created with the situation we're using it.

We have a sliding slidebar that goes inside content div. And buttons for hiding / showing effect with a tooltip. The sliding effect based on jQuery UI slide.

The issue is:

When we click on hide sidebar button, and at the same time moves mouse out of button hover at the time of slide animation, then some times the tooltip doesn't gets hidden, and stays over there on the page.

This happens also on show sidebar too. And when it happens it looks very bad and buggy.

How can we fix this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Answered on bootstrap forum by Richard ( https://github.com/r1ch0)

Just manually hide the tooltip when you click the button, before you trigger the slide animation.

```
$('#button').on('click', function () {
  $(this).tooltip('hide')
  $('#sidebar').slide() // replace with slide animation
})
```

Copied from: https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/3446

Posted here just because someone else can find it.

Comment: Thanks for this solution. Is there a way to achieve a similar effect without javascript, simply with HTML & CSS?

Comment: @ThibaudClement Glad to know its helpful. No, I am unable to find any solution just with HTML and CSS!

Comment: for a global effect this can be used :
`$('body').on('click','*', function () {
        $(this).tooltip('hide')
    });`

Answer (score 3):

I used Krunal contribution (+1 btw), that helped a lot me but did not completly solved the issue.
The tooltip disappears when I clic on the button, but comes back and gets stuck again when my mouse hovers it, until I click somewhere else.

So i figured out that the tooltip appears while *hovering*, and also while *focusing* an element.
Finally i wrote this :

```
$('button').on('click', function () {
    $(this).blur()
})
```

And it works well.
Thanks.

Comment: Perfect - this fixed an issue I was having where the tooltip was hidden but still taking up space and not allowing elements underneath it to register clicks properly

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be a proper solution to this (one that doesn't involve you clean up manually) on https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/pull/4104, hopefully will be released soon.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the bootstrap tool tip, then how about adding a delay option:

```
jQuery('#example').popover(delay: { show: 100, hide: 100 })
```

If the tool tip is like from an alt tag in an image, then use jQuery to remove it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("img").removeAttr("alt");
});
</script>
```